# Battleship- Best Next Move

Tags: strategy, board-games

Mason likes the game [Battleship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_%28game%29), but he doesn't win much. However, Sherry, his opponent, is so confident in her skill and luck that she has agreed to let Mason have his five friends help him.

Sherry's method for placing her ships is completely random. Each side has 5 ships, and they reach the position below, where Mason has sunk all of Sherry's ships except for her Battleship, which is 4 units long.

The board is 10x10, and all ships must be fully on the board and placed either horizontally or vertically. The green H's represent ships that Mason has already sunk. The red M's represent his misses.

[image]

Each of Mason's friends want to help, but they cannot seem to agree on the best move. Clair insists on F2, but Mike is sure about H2. Bartholomew recommends D8 and Jessica tells him to play G6. Lastly, Pat says to play D5.

Put his friends in order from "Best Advice" to "Worst Advice". Did one of them find the best move?

Comment: Nice to see a new game coming onto the site! I created a tag for battleship, since I don't think you have enough rep to create tags.

Comment: @Micah The hits and misses are irrelevant to the puzzle.  You can simply treat them all as *"positions already tried that didn't hit the 4 space battleship"*.  If anything, it's a distraction, which is why none of the answers discuss already hit ships.

Comment: Having played lots of battleship, I can say the proposed method of solution to solve the puzzle is not correct. Psychology of the opponent is more reliable.

Comment: @Joshua I think so too, so I included a phrase when I created the question to combat that: "Sherry's method for placing her ships is completely random."

Comment: @AdamDavis: While not a factor for this particular arrangement, hits and misses--and even the sequencing thereof--could be relevant if hits were not 100% accounted for by sunk ships; house rule variations could also play a role.  For example, if one plays that a person is told "hit and sunk" without being told what was sunk, then the above map could have the battleship at b10-e10 (already sunk) and the carrier at a6-a10 (with one hit).

Comment: @supercat I agree, they are not relevant to this puzzle. They might be relevant to other puzzles, but not this one.

Comment: What are the adjacency rules? Some people disallow Moore neighbourhood adjacency, and some people disallow von Neumann neighbourhood adjacency.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

D5 covers 4 locations

D8 covers 3

F2 covers 2

H2 covers 1

G6 covers 0

E5 is the best; it covers 5 locations.

Comment: This is clearly the right reasoning if your goal is to hit something next turn. It's less clear that it's correct if you have a different goal. e.g. it's easy to see that, except for G6, there isn't any difference between the options if your goal is "win four turns from now", since that requires a guess of the exact location of the battleship. (I also assume that all places for the battleship are equally likely)

Comment: @Hurkyl They are equally likely; the OP said so. I mean it doesn't seem to me that this question is asking for future moves. If you want to do an answer on that, you can

Comment: What "best" means is rather vague; I thought it worth explicitly pointing out. It is not uncommon for people to *mean* "the play that gives me the best chance of winning", but do an analysis for something only loosely related to that goal, such as the odds of scoring a hit immediately. (also, conditional probability can be rather unintuitive; I wanted to just assume it works out the way we hope it would, and felt compelled to document the fact I assume)

Comment: @Hurkyl: Consider what happens if `E5` does not result in a *hit* but a *miss*: You would have *eliminated* those 5 locations from future consideration.

Comment: I agree with Hurkyl. Consider [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P0LfO.png) where red=miss. Using the heuristic "play the move that covers the most ship locations," you would play at A. If you play at A, then it may take four moves worst case to locate the battleship. But if you don't play at A, there is a way to get a sure hit in three moves! (Can you see it?) It is not clear which move is better; presumably it depends on how close your opponent is to winning.

Comment: @Lopsy: Good visualization. You're right.

Comment: @Hurkyl Excellent point. Lopsy or DevSolar- Could either of you (or someone else) apply the idea Hurkyl presented to the board position and see what the "best" set of moves would be if you need to win in 2 moves, 3 moves, etc. ?

Comment: @JLee: I think a better goal might be "best set of moves would be the minimum set to guarantee a hit, with a sub-priority of hitting sooner rather than later".  Actually... maybe not.  I think your suggestion is better.

Comment: @Mooing Duck And thus was born the idea for your first question on the site. And I'm not being sarcastic. There aren't many Battleship questions, so you make one with that twist. I'd try to solve it.

Comment: Actually, it seems like there would be a way to balance the probability of a ship (hit now) being in a place along with the multi-turn probability of finding a ship (hit soon) to come up with an optimal starting strategy given a board position... I'll see if I can code it.

Comment: @Lopsy Considering optimal play, beginning with guess A the player wins in an average of 83/14 moves, min 4, max 8. Playing for the sure hit player wins in average of 84/14 moves, min 4, max 8. So your sure hit move is slightly worse because it provides a tiny bit less information than a hit/miss on A.

Comment: @Lopsy  And just for kicks, no opening move does better than A in optimal play.

Comment: @Hurkyl - Strictly speaking, you are correct. One needs to consider not only what happens if a guess results in a "hit" but also what happens if that guess results in a "miss". Consider a choice between a spot that has a 90% chance of getting a "hit" and another that has a 60% chance of getting a "hit". (Note: That can't happen with this setup.) In this hypothetical case, it's the 60% hit that's the better choice. From an information theory perspective, the best guess is the one that comes closest to 50/50. In this case, all the choices are well below 50% (even E5), so it's best to choose E5.

Comment: @David: That's still a greedy *heuristic*, though: a priori, you don't know that the move that gives you the most information immediately can be followed up with 'good' choices; e.g. it's possible that the sequence of two moves that is best by this heuristic begins with some other move.

Comment: @Hurkyl: For example, use as a heuristic the expected value of the number of guesses needed to sink the battleship. The best move is the guess that minimizes this expected value. And you're right; the best guess from that strategy isn't necessarily the same as the best guess from a greedy heuristic.

Answer (score 22):

The "best" move for this puzzle is the one most likely to hit the ship in one shot, as the puzzle doesn't allow for further follow up shots.  There are 23 possible positions for that ship, and 68 spaces where a shot could be placed.

Due to the size of the ship and previously placed shots, we can find both where shots cannot possibly hit the ship, and places for shots which cover more than one position.

For instance, G6 cannot hit the ship because previous shots placed at G4, G7, F6, and I6 would have most certainly hit that ship given that the ship is four spaces long.  So G6 could not result in a hit.

Taking F2 as an example, there are 5 spaces in a vertical column where shots have not previously been placed.  A 4 length ship could exist in the four top spaces, or four bottom spaces, and F2 covers both possibilities.  Thus, F2 would hit 2 out of those 21 possible ship positions, giving you a 8.7% chance of hitting the ship.

If we perform this analysis for every possible shot we can take, we can find how many positions each shot could cover:

[image: Image of battleship board with each available space filled with the number of positions it covers]

We find then that the best space for a shot which covers the most of the 21 available positions is E5, covering 5 positions, and having a 22% chance of hitting the ship.  This is not among the suggestions the friends made, though.  Their shots rank as follows, from best to worst:

```
Space   Positions    Probability
D5      4            17%
D8      3            13%
F2      2             8.7%
H2      1             4.3%
G6      0             0.0%
```

Once E5 is taken you've removed 5 possible locations, leaving 18 if it didn't hit the ship:

[image: Image of battleship board with each available space filled with the number of positions it covers after another shot on E5]

Comment: It's not clear if your first sentence is a *definition* of the word best, or if you're trying to assert something by it.

Comment: +1 Very well-explained. Hurkyl has brought up an excellent point though, in the comments of the accepted answer. Consider the usual case where your opponent cannot win within the next few moves. Then, it is likely that the "best" move would be based on a strategy that looks at, for example, the 3 shots that will cover the most squares. Sometimes the "best" single shot will be one of those 3, but not necessarily (consider Lopsy's image).

Comment: @Hurkyl I've altered the sentence to be more specific, and removed following irrelevant shots.  Continuing the game was interesting to me, but ultimately irrelevant to the puzzle as presented and, as you suggested, muddied the definition of "best".

Comment: @JLee You are right, thanks for pointing out the comments elsewhere.  As the puzzle is presented considering only one move ahead (ie, each didn't suggest a sequence of moves, just one) then I'm taking the path where we assume he wants to maximize his possibility of finding the ship in only one move.  As it turns out, the answer is still the same even if you look ahead for two additional moves, but since there's no upper limit to that analysis (do we look at the next 3, 5, or 10 best moves?) then it seems reasonable to address just the one move he is about to take.

Comment: @Adam Davis Yes, all that sounds good, and it was my intention to consider the best single move when creating the puzzle, so I could have phrased the question better, avoiding the use of the word "best", but I just wanted to point out (after reading Hurkyl's comments) that the single-move solution wouldn't necessarily be the "best" move.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the number of possible eliminations:

D8 covers 3 possible battleship locations (Bartholomew)

F2 covers 2 possible battleship locations, and also follows a more spread out pattern of ships (Clair)

D5 covers 2 possible battleship locations but leaves open a third, D6-D9 (Pat)

H2 covers 1 possible battleship location (Mike)

And Jessica is obviously on Sherry's team, since G6 covers 0 possible battleship locations.

Tip of the hat to @JonTheMon, I would have also recommended E5.

Comment: Did you get your D5 and D8 reversed?

Comment: No. D8 does cover 3 possible locations. A8-D8, D5-D8, and D6-D10. I went back and forth on D8/F2 being number 2...

Comment: Ah, right, I see what you're getting at.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the order from best to worst is

D5 - Covers a total of 3 placements and 9 spaces of the board where the ship could be. Also a slightly better shape (3 bars of a +)
D8 - Covers 2 placements and 8 spaces
F2 - 1 placement, 5 spaces
H2 - 1 placement, 4 spaces
G6 - There is no chance that the last ship is in this square, there is no segment going through this square that is 4 long.

And the best move I'd say is E5, since that hits up to 3 positions and gets 10 spaces of coverage.

Answer (score 3):

Since some of the locations overlap, it may be better to look at how many squares can be eliminated by each guess. The end result will be somewhat different.

> A miss on F2 eliminates the following other squares from contention: D2, E2, G2, and H2.
>
> For H2, it doesn't eliminate any other squares
>
> D8 also eliminates B8, C8, D6, D7, D9
>
> G6 technically eliminates itself, but it already wasn't an option
>
> D5, although it eliminates a lot of potential battleship positions, only actually takes 1 other spot out of the running - C2. All the other spots are still possible battleship locations in another configuration.

So by this metric, D8 is the best of the 5 guesses, potentially eliminating itself plus 5 other squares. That's followed by F2, then H2 and D5 tied, and G6 in last.

I'm interested to hear people's opinions on which of the two metrics are "best". To me, the potential flaw in looking at it from the number of ship locations that a spot is part of is that some spots are part of other potential locations too. So guessing D5 doesn't help you as much with regard to B5 because B5 could still be part of the ship.

Also, by this measure, E5 eliminates 4 additional spots - C5, E4, E6, E7, so not as good as D8.

Comment: E5 is the better choice.

Comment: There's no point in eliminating squares.  You're interested in eliminating positions the battleship can be in.  The more positions it could hit the better--hence E5.